# What are the settings to get a perfect picture in cloudy weather (low light)?

Tags: image-quality, low-light

Using a GoPro Hero 4 Silver's default settings I took a picture in cloudy weather (low light). Here is the result I got which is very very bad!
[image: out of focus image]

What settings do I need to get a good result in cloudy weather?

Comment: What's a perfect picture?

Comment: with more light and exposure, like https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TleRti7BXgQ/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: You think that is a perfect picture?

Answer (score 4):

The image looks out of focus. As the focusing sensor doesn't perform as good in lower light as it does on a bright sunny day, I don't think there's much you can do in this regard except try to take another picture which might get better focus.

I don't believe the GoPro offers manual control over focus, so that solution is not available in this case.

Comment: It could also be camera motion combined with a slow shutter speed. With a lens that wide it is sometimes hard to tell the difference when nothing is in focus.